"Es inestable" vs. "está inestable"
When it comes to the phrase "La conexión es inestable," why is ser used as the standard means of conveying instability?

This message frequently appears within the context of the Internet, like Zoom or TikTok. It would seem to me that estar would be more appropriate because the Internet connection could just as easily stabilize in the next few seconds, as it often does in real life. Why is ser the chosen verb for an impermanent condition?

By the way, the native Spanish speaker is not "picking between two verbs that mean the same thing".  To the native speaker, there are two different verbs, and one of them is more appropriate to the sentence being constructed.

I would argue that it could be considered an impermanent but recurring condition. In which case you could consider the instability of the connection to be characteristic of the connection, rather than just the temporary state for a few minutes.
Consider the usage with some other adjective:

"Ella es feliz." -> She is a happy person in general
"Ella está feliz." -> She is currently happy

I think the same applies here that you could use either "es" or "está", but the former implies that your connection is generally unstable on a recurring basis, like  you live in a rural area etc.
As an aside, note the timeline in your chart far predates the existence of the internet, and there is a (possibly coincidental) uptick in "está" usage that seems to rise with the internet's ubiquity.

With respect to historical developments on the time line.  Between about 1850 and 1900 people could have been talking about the telegraph.  Then from 1900 to 1990 it would have been phone lines and/or radio and TV.  But I have no idea what they could be referring to prior to 1850.

Are there other things that might have been estable or inestable?  Things like the balance of sea power between england and spain?  Or the value of currency?  Did all of those other contexts establish inestable as an intrinsic property of an object rether than an extrinsic property?  BTW, II don't think of a connection that is always down as inestable.

With certain nouns referring to events, "ser" can be used to refer to a transient, non-permanent condition. I think this is so because the noun itself carries the sense of temporariness.
"Conexión" can refer to the physical connection or to the situation of two things being connected. When used with the former meaning, "la conexión es inestable" will mean that the physical connection is not good; when used with the latter meaning, "la conexión es inestable" will mean that there is instability in the action of connecting, so to speak.
In "la conexión está inestable" it is clear we are referring to the current instability of the connection.
Another noun that comes to mind is "situación". If we say "la situación es caótica", we mean that the current state of events is chaotic. "Situación" is one such noun denoting a temporary state which does not need to take "estar" for the sentence to refer to a non-permanent condition.

I can understand situacion. If we say "la situacion es caotica," it makes sense because while the situation may not last forever, it is inherently caotic. When I was in Madrid, I heard this phrase a lot to refer to protests. Those protests didn't last forever, but the nature of the protests inherently chaotic. (They weren't magically going to become silent/blissful.)

With instability, I feel differently. Today, an Internet connection is always present during a video call. When the Internet chokes a little bit, it temporarily becomes unstable. In those shorts moments, la conexion ESTA inestable. Other things, like chemical bonds, are intrinsically unstable, and I would use ser there.

@SebastianPojman-Malo One of the meanings of the verb ser implies to have or to exist as a synonym for to subsist, to last or to be maintained.
And this is a legitimate use of the verb ser in Spanish. That is why it is valid to say "la conexión es inestable", which although it may be something transitory, to me as a Spanish speaker, it sounds odd for me to say "la conexión está inestable", even though I understand that it is something temporary and not the usual thing.
